# Does mineral oil have unusual wicking properties?

Tags: surface-tension

Can we talk about baby oil, or specifically mineral oil?  Some [overclocker's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overclocking) use it for [immersion cooling](https://www.rochaksite.com/mineral-oil-cooled-pc-aquarium-pcs/) their computers.  There are hints, suggestions and rumours that one of the issues with this technique is wicking of the oil through the connecting leads.  So for example, people have reported that the oil will seep upwards inside an Ethernet or power cable and come out of the other end through the connector.  None of this seems particularly scientific and the evidence appears very anecdotal.

Is there any basis in physics for this wicking behaviour in mineral oil?  If I dangle one end of a vertical network cable in a bath of baby oil, will oil eventually ooze out of the top end?

Comment: Given that water can and will get into power, data, and coax it certainly is not surprising that baby oil could infiltrate similar cables.

Comment: @JonCuster Ah, not quite what I meant.  I think the anecdotal evidence suggests that the oil will climb upwards against gravity within the cable sheaths.  So the question is whether there's something different about mineral oil from plain water?  Super strong capillary action?  Uber surface tension?  Magic?

Comment: Water can wick quite a ways up tightly bundled wires. No magic involved, just surface tension.

Comment: @JonCuster So your answer to my question is "no"?  Can you quantify this distance please - feet or millimetres?